# Is this a correct BTRFS incremental backup strategy?

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, btrfs, incremental-backup

Assuming /home is my BTRFS partition (to keep backups of) & /storage as my secondary disk (to store backups on), will this work?

Initial Backup (8th Sept 2020):

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /home/backup
btrfs send /home/backup > /storage/home.bin
```

Next Day (9th Sept 2020):

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /home/backup-new
btrfs send -p /home/backup /home/backup-new > /storage/home.incr.20200909
btrfs subvolume delete /home/backup
mv /home/backup-new /home/backup
```

Next Day (10th Sept 2020):

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /home/backup-new
btrfs send -p /home/backup /home/backup-new > /storage/home.incr.20200910
btrfs subvolume delete /home/backup
mv /home/backup-new /home/backup
```

....
and so on.

And in order to restore, just create a fresh BTRFS volume somewhere and re-play "btrfs recieve" in proper order of stored full backup file and increments.

Answer (score 1):

I should work, but you have to keep all incremental files because any missing incremental file will defeat the restore operation after this date.

If you can format a partition of your secondary disk in btrfs, it would be more practical because you would be able to use "btrfs receive" just after the "btrfs send" for incremental backups:

Initial Backup (8th Sept 2020):

```sh
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /home/backup
btrfs send /home/backup|btrfs receive /storage # line modified
mv /storage/backup /storage/home.20200908 # line added
```

Next Day (9th Sept 2020):

```sh
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /home/backup-new
btrfs send -p /home/backup /home/backup-new|btrfs receive /storage # line modified
mv /storage/backup-new /storage/home.20200909 # line added
btrfs subvolume delete /home/backup
mv /home/backup-new /home/backup
```

So that the last backup is directly available (e.g. to easily recover a file deleted by mistake), backups can be rotated (e.g. to keep only backups of the last week) and intermediary backups can be deleted.